# How to exclude certain folders by path using the "find" command in Linux?

Tags: find

I have the following in a directory:

```
1/
2/
3/
4/
5/
active -> 1
previous -> 2
```

Those are folders, as well as two symbolic links pointing to a folder. I want to delete all folders that are not being pointed to in the symbolic links, and not delete the symbolic links. I have tried the following

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -path "$(readlink -f active)" -not -path "$(readlink -f previous)"
```

This still returns the two directories I want excluded. What's wrong here?

Comment: I still don't want it to remove the actual directories they're pointing to though, so how do I filter them out?

Comment: Hm, do you want to actually remove the folders and their contents, or just filter them from the `find` output? You said you want to delete all that are not pointed to by the symlinks, but the `find` expression seems to try to filter out exactly the ones pointed to by the symlinks? So, could you [edit] the question to clarify a bit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. `readlink -f` returns an absolute path, `-path` expects a relative one prefixed with `./`.
2. Some versions of `readlink` return a path with a trailing slash for a symlink, which is refused by `find` (tested with Ubuntu, not reproducible on Gentoo).

This worked for me on Ubuntu, but it may not be the most elegant solution:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -path "./$(readlink active | sed "s/\/$//")" -not -path "./$(readlink previous | sed "s/\/$//")"
```

Here's a slightly more straightforward alternative using `realpath`, tested on Gentoo; it could be the more portable one:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -not -path "./$(realpath --relative-to=. active)" -not -path "./$(realpath --relative-to=. previous)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using some GNUisms (`-not`, `-mindepth`, `-maxdepth`), you could do:

```
find -L . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -xtype l \
  ! -samefile active ! -samefile previous
```

Then you wouldn't have to depend on the symlinks targets being in the right form (`./1` if using `find .`, not `1`, nor `././1` nor `/path/to/1`) and escape wildcard characters in them (if the symlink was to `*`, you'd need a `-path './[*]'` for instance).

Or with `zsh`:

```
print -rl ./*(D/e:'[[ ! $REPLY -ef active && ! $REPLY -ef previous ]]':)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not run `find` only in the directories you're interested in, instead of trying to filter  out the others?

```
$ find ./active/ ./previous/
```

or

```
$ find "./$(readlink active)" "./$(readlink previous)" -maxdepth 0
./1
./2
```

Or if you meant you wanted `find` to match exactly the ones the symlinks *don't* point to:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d  -not -path "./$(readlink active)" -not -path "./$(readlink previous)"
./3
./4
./5
```